# Android traces : Error during call stack reconstruction

Tags: android

I record traces on my android project by calling

```
Debug.startMethodTracing("MY AWESOME TRACE");
```

This usually works as a charm, but when trying to open my .trace file with Android Studio I get this issue :

```
Unexpected error while parsing trace file: Error during call stack reconstruction. Attempt to exit from method XXX while in method YYY
```

Has anyone encountered this error message ?

Cheers,